# Express routes and Socket.io

Tags: node.js, express, routes, socket.io

What is the best way to connect socket.io to my routes?

I use socket.io to push data to clients as it happens. I have my index page that, for example may have comments coming in and being pushed to other clients. Simple.

However, I want to be able to click a user and then have the page change to a page for that user and then get in real time all the comments of that user.

There has to be a better way than what I'm doing right now.

I'm currently...

```
app.get('/users/:uid', function(req, res){
 res.render("user", { user : req.user, id: JSON.stringify(req.params.uid)});
});
```

Then I'm just using jade to save the variable so I can use it in another javascript file

```
script
        var id = !{id};
```

Then in that over javascript I just have it connect to socket IO and say I'm looking for this user.

I've worked with session socket io. It never seemed right to keep this sort of information in there either. It also occasionally didn't save the session correctly or update it from page to page causing problems. I'm using a different session store than I was in that project though so things may be different. connect-mongo now.

What is the best way to do something like this? I'm sure I'm not the first person to ask this even though I wasn't able to find anything.

I'm also using passport.socketIo.

Comment: No need to send uid via root, socket.io already handsake data: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing

Comment: thank you!!! Can't believe I never knew that!

Comment: console.log("url: " + socket.handshake.url); just gives me: 
url: /socket.io/1/?t=1387828935995
Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: http://howtonode.org/socket-io-auth , get cookies, then find session id, then you can know every about the user.

Comment: I'm already using passport.socketio to get all the user information. I could use session.socket.io to store the current page they are trying to view in the session. That is what I used to do but it creates other problems and does not consistently work. I could also use socket.handshake.headers.referer to get the address they are coming from but I still have to parse it and that seems like it could introduce other problems. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Struggled with this for awhile, asked again and this is how I solved it.

[Routes in Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20980349/routes-in-socket-io)