# Routes in Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Is there a way to tell what route a user is connecting to socket.io from?

For example, I have a route that has /user/:id. The page renders and socket.io connects. Socket.io needs to know what route the client is connecting from as well as the :id so it can send the related data.

How can this be done?

What I've tried:
I've tried session sockets but that was a mess. I got it to work but there are quite a few issues with using session sockets this way. Ruling that out. Currently, I'm passing the :id from the route to jade and then saving id as a variable then when I connect from socket.io I send user_init with the id. MESSY but works just fine.

Comment: have you tried namespaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just wrote a small route parser for my socket.io

```
var express = require('express')
    , sioRouter = new express.Router();

sio.on('connection', function(socket){

    var route = sioRouter.match('GET', socket.handshake.headers.referer);
    if (route && route.callbacks.length) {
        route.callbacks[0](socket, route.params);
    }

    sioRouter.get('/users/:id', function(socket, params){}
}
```

boom - the documentation for express.Router() is non existent. I found someone else doing router.match and it works great. If anyone knows where I can find documentation on the express router please comment!